# Aligning Contribution Items in the Status Line

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have a handful of StatusLineContributionItem and have added them to a SubStatusLineManager. Currently all the ContributionItems are aligned to the right side of my StatusLine. I would like them Left aligned but using `subStatusLineManager.("BEGIN_GROUP", statusLineContributionItem)` just increases the size of the actual contribution item.

Answer (score 0):

From my research it appears that the left side is reserved for status text ex: `statusLineManager.setMessage("Hello World!");` and the right side is reserved for status items and progress indicators.